# Settin up Wifi for Multiple users

Tags: wireless-networking, multiple-users

I have over ten people using a wifi set up for an apartment complex. I have to restart the modem a few times a day so everyone can get connected. The message Limited access appears and sometimes I never get connected. Is there a way to keep sending new IP addresses so i won't have to restart..?

Comment: You need to head to the DHCP settings in the router's setting page and see what is the range for that. You can also extend the lease of the IP there as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that the router is not up to the job and is almost certainly running out of resources.

I recommend getting a better router. You don't actually need to replace the Internet router. Just get a WiFi extender. Have a look at Edimax, they have several boxes that would do the job without costing that much.

With a WiFi extender, you can also set multiple boxes on the same WiFi network quite easily so that the boxes can share the load. Simple make sure that each box gets a fixed IP address on the same subnet as the main Internet router and make sure that the WiFi settings for each are the same (The SSID, channel and security settings).

Answer (score 0):

As @Darius said in the comment, check the DHCP setting on the router and ensure that the range of IP addresses it gives out is high enough (keep it at around 15, at the minimum). Another thing you could do is reduce the lease period of the addresses given by DHCP so that the same IP addresses can be reused.